# Using random rnd inside a method causes multiple errors

Tags: c#, random

Having problem with the method down below. The current error I get is "it does not return any value" If I put the return num outside of the brackets, it does not exist in the current context.
If I remove the brackets all together I get:

Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement
The name 'rnd' does not exist in the current context

I've done multiple methods before without this issue. What am I missing?

```
 public static int generateNumber(int timesUserWantsToGuess)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= timesUserWantsToGuess; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int num = rnd.Next(1, 50);
                return num;
            }


        }
```

Comment: What happens when `timesUserWantsToGuess = 0`? The compiler is simply rejecting that possibility. Fix the first error first and please *search* for error messages.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this method? If `timesUserWantsToGuess` is 0, the loop won't return a value. If `timesUserWantsToGuess` is >= 1, then the loop will only be done once. Then there's the whole issue with declaring a new `Random` per iteration, which is going to (more than likely) produce the same random number.

Comment: Also consider case where `timesUserWantsToGuess < 0`. The compiler has no way of knowing that isn't a valid value to pass to this function.

Comment: Actually this will have a return value if `timesUserWantsToGuess` is 0, but if it is less than zero it would skip the `for` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off you have a mismatch of semantics. You are returning a single `int`, but are executing and returning within a loop.

If you *actually* wanted to return a *collection* of ints, you could do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> generateNumber(int timesUserWantsToGuess)
{
   //Optional, but good error checking
   if (timesUserWantsToGuess <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentException("Invalid guess count");

   Random rnd = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < timesUserWantsToGuess; i++)
    {
        int num = rnd.Next(1, 50);
        yield return num;
    }
}
```

Note the use of `yield` to return the next object in the sequence. You also shouldn't instantiate `Random` in a tight loop, since it will cause the same values to be generated (same seed). Also, using `<=` in the for conditional will yield one more iteration than the passed value, so I switched to `<`.

If you didn't want a loop at all, then just remove it and your problem will be solved. At the moment, the loop semantic and the rest of your code mismatch, which is causing you the problem.

Comment: It may (or may not) also be worth adding a check for `timeUserWantsToGuess < 0` and throwing an `InvalidOperationException` rather than just returning an empty sequence as it feels like it ought to be a serious error.

Comment: @MattBurland Agreed, though I would use an `ArgumentException`. Added as an optional piece

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that since the `return` statement exists inside a loop, the compiler assumes there's a chance it could execute without ever hitting the block, and thus won't return. This could logically happen if `timesUserWantsToGuess` is less than 0 - the loop never enters in this case. The reason this code compiles if the `return` statement is outside the block is that by being outside the block, the execution guarantees it'll hit the `return` (or throw an exception) at some point.

If you remove the brackets on a block in C# (`if`, `for`, `foreach`, `lock`, and `while` all do this to my knowledge) you are saying that the block contains only the next line (which is indented by convention) and nothing more. Since variable declaration on a one-line ("embedded") statement can't be used anywhere else syntactically, it doesn't make sense to do it, so the compiler forbids it altogether. Be noted it is also possible to declare a variable in a block without using it, as long as the block is bracketed.

Finally, there's a huge semantic mismatch in the logic of returning a single value during a loop like this: see @BradleyDotNET's answer on `yield return` statements

Comment: Actually it would only skip the `for` loop if `timesUserWantsToGuess` is less than zero.